# Single table cell is one pixel shorter than the rest?

Tags: html, css, image, padding

I'm very new and very confused. I'm trying to build a page right now, located here: http://operation-rebuild.org/meet-the-staff/ and I cannot figure out, for the life of me, why certain table cells are showing up 1 pixel different from the others. On Firefox, the third image (the blonde) is 1 pixel too wide to match the label "COORDINATOR". On Google Chrome, there is a single pixel gap between the image and the label on the first three images. On the last image, there is no such gap, but the label itself is a pixel shorter than the image. They are all using the same elements so I don't understand what is causing the difference or why it is browser-specific. Can anyone tell what's going on?

Also, just a side note, there appears to be a 5px padding surrounding all of my images. I have no idea where it's coming from. It's not in my CSS and I've scoured the theme's stylesheet to no avail. I've temporarily gotten rid of the gap by just setting the margin of the black/white labels to -5px, but it's frustrating. If anyone with a more advanced eye can spot the error I would appreciate it!

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 0px solid #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table.no-spacing {
  border-spacing: 0;
}

#table1 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.staff,
td,
th {
  padding: 5px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.stafftitle {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -5px;
  width: 201px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #000;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
}

.staffname {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 203px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table class="no-spacing" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-829" src="http://operation-rebuild.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/mesite1-218x300.png" alt="" width="218" height="300" /></td>
    <td><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-830" src="http://operation-rebuild.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/lexsite1-218x300.png" alt="" width="218" height="300" /></td>
    <td><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-827" src="http://operation-rebuild.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/taylorsite1-218x300.png" alt="" width="218" height="300" /></td>
    <td><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-828" src="http://operation-rebuild.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/kelseysite1-218x300.png" alt="" width="218" height="300" /></td>
  </tr>
  <div class="staff">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="stafftitle">DIRECTOR</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="stafftitle">COORDINATOR</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="stafftitle">COORDINATOR</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="stafftitle">COORDINATOR</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="staffname">Rebecca McGory</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="staffname">Alexis Nasta</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="staffname">Taylor McNeil</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="staffname">Kelsey Brown</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't have a `<div>` between table rows. Any content other than table elements must go in a `<td>`, otherwise it's invalid. Should also be noted that you open the `<div>` inside the table, but the closing tag is *outside* the table.

Comment: image padding is coming from `.staff,
td,
th {
  padding: 5px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}`

Comment: I fixed the div but I'm not sure what you mean about putting it all in a <td>. Can you explain? I tried dividing it into two tables but that didn't help.

As for the image padding - the "staff" div isn't around the images, only the labels. I checked just to be sure and got rid of that padding and also got rid of my -5 margin offset, and the padding around the image is still there.

Comment: `table, th, td` and `.staff, td, th` both target padding on the `td` elements. The last one in the file takes precedence. That being the `padding: 5px;`.

Comment: For anyone wondering - I just found the fix, and it was a stupid logistical error. I realized that the first AND third images were both a pixel wider than the labels. The width of my images was 218, the padding was 5px - it was an odd number so every other cell was one pixel off. Changed the padding to 6px and it solved it. Thanks for the replies!

I still can't find where the image padding itself is coming from, so if anyone has ideas I'm all ears. Even just set in a table, with no padding and no margins, all 4 images are surrounded by a 5px pattern. It be somewhere in the theme.

Comment: just change `.staff,
td,
th {
  padding: 5px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}` to `.staff {
  padding: 5px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}` and that will fix it

Comment: Sorry, you were right. It worked. Thank you!